# How do I prove by induction?

Tags: proof-writing

For example if i wanted to prove: 
$1^2 + \dots + n^2 = \frac {n(n + 1)(2n + 1)} {6}$
by induction.
I'm not sure where to start. 
Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, where does 'k' come from? Do I just substitute k for n?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prove for the **base case**, n=1:

$$1^{2} = \frac{1(1+1)(2+1)}{6} = \frac{2\cdot3}{6}=1$$

The "sum" of just $1^2$ is indeed 1. Base case proven.

Now for the **induction step**, proving that it holds for n+1:

Observe that for $1^{2} + 2^{2} +... + n^{2}$, the sum including $n+1$ equals the original summation plus the $n+1$ term: $1^{2} + 2^{2} + ... + n^{2} + (n+1)^{2}$, i.e. equals $ \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} + (n+1)^{2}$.

So all we need to do is show that $\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} + (n+1)^{2} = \frac{(n+1)((n+1)+1)(2(n+1)+1)}{6}$.

*(Edit: To be clear: $\frac{(n+1)((n+1)+1)(2(n+1)+1)}{6}$ is $\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ with $n+1$ substituted in for $n$.)*

Let's do that now:
$$\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} + (n+1)^{2} = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} + \frac{6(n+1)^{2}}{6}$$
$$ = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)+6(n+1)^2}{6}$$
$$ = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)+6(n^{2}+2n+1)}{6}$$
$$ = \frac{n(2n^{2}+3n+1)+6n^{2}+12n+6)}{6}$$
$$ = \frac{2n^{3}+3n^{2}+n+6n^{2}+12n+6}{6}$$
$$ = \frac{2n^{3}+9n^{2}+13n+6}{6}$$

Having simplified this, we'll now show that it is equal to $\frac{(n+1)((n+1)+1)(2(n+1)+1)}{6}$:

$$\frac{(n+1)((n+1)+1)(2(n+1)+1)}{6} = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)(2n+3)}{6}$$
$$ = \frac{(n^{2}+3n+2)(2n+3)}{6}$$
$$ = \frac{2n^{3}+6n^{2}+4n+3n^{2}+9n+6}{6}$$
$$ = \frac{2n^{3}+9n^{2}+13n+6}{6}$$

And we're done!

Comment: You could have started the induction at zero. In that case the sum of all squares from one to zero is the empty sum, which sums to zero.

Comment: @BabyDragon I don't think I could have. OP's index started at $1$, as in the problem statement: $1^{2}+...+n^{2}$.

Comment: That is why it is an empty sum. In particular, we may write formally, $\Sigma_{n=1}^0 n^2$, which is read as the sum of all integers greater then or equal to one and less than or equal to zero. But their are no such numbers, so we are summing over an empty set. When we sum over an empty set, we get the answer zero. This is not much of an issue here, since it is easy to deal with the case when $n=1$. However, their are cases where this is a useful thing, since in other problems, calculating the $n=1$ case can be a real chore, but the case where $n=0$ is true by this sort of reasoning.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum and in particular http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum#Significance_of_.22terms.22_of_an_empty_sum

Comment: Oh, that's actually quite interesting! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is not induction, I still find it quite amusing that Leibniz (inventing the differential calculus almost simultaneously with Newton) solved these kind of problems with some sort of difference method with great similarity to his differential calculus:

First we define the differences of a sequence: For instance the sequence $x^2$ for integers $x$ has (first order) differences
$$
dx^2=(x+1)^2-x^2=2x+1
$$
or more generally $f:\mathbb Z\rightarrow\mathbb Z$ has differences $df=f(x+1)-f(x)$ in modern function notation. With this definition it can be seen (using the binomial theorem) that
$$
\begin{align}
dx^4&=4x^3+6x^2+4x+1\\
dx^3&=3x^2+3x+1\\
dx^2&=2x+1\\
dx&=1\\
d(kf)&=k\ df\\
dk&=0
\end{align}
$$
where $k$ denotes some constant. One notices that taking differences of polynomial expressions yields polynomials of one degree less.

Now your problem corresponds to saying $df=(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1$ and searching for a polynomial expression $f(x)$ solving this. From the degree it follows that
$$
f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d
$$
Therefore
$$
\begin{align}
x^2+2x+1&=df\\
&=a(3x^2+3x+1)+b(2x+1)+c\\
&=3ax^2+(3a+2b)x+(a+b+c)
\end{align}
$$
Now to match coefficients of these two expressions for the same quadratic we must have
$$
\begin{align}
3a&=1\\
3a+2b&=2\\
a+b+c&=1
\end{align}
$$
which is a system of linear equations that can be solved to get $a=\frac{1}{3}$, $b=\frac{1}{2}$ and $c=\frac{1}{6}$. The constant term $d$ can then be determined from the initial value $f(1)=1$ leading to $d=0$. So we have found that
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\frac{1}{3}x^3+\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{6}x\\
&{}\\
&{}\\
&=\frac{x(x+1)(2x+1)}{6}
\end{align}
$$
Both note how this method is constructive *we do not need know the answer beforehand as it just jumps out from the method*, but also how it has great similarities to integration of a function with a given initial value.

Comment: Wow. This is such a cool answer. I was really just awestruck when I read it.

Comment: @Newb: I know this method from the historical article **'Historio et Origo Calculi Differentialis'** presumably written (but not published) by Leibniz himself short before his death in 1716, pretending to write as *a close friend of Leibniz* claiming to describe the 'true story' of how and by whom the differential calculus was invented. An answer to the dispute with the English *Royal Acadamy of Sciences* who claimed Newton to be the 'true inventor'. It can be found on page 51 here: http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/tam212/rvc_Child_1920.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Since $\frac{1(1 +1)(2+1)}{6} = 1$, then base case holds. Suppose result holds for $n$. Then

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} i^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2 + (n+1)^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n + 1)}{6} + (n+1)^2 $$

$$ \frac{n(n+1)(2n + 1)}{6} + (n+1)^2 = \frac{(n+1)[n(2n+1) + 6(n+1)}{6} = \frac{(n+1)(2n^2 + 7n + 1)}{6} =_{*} \frac{(n+1)(n+2)(2n + 3)}{6} = \frac{(n+1)((n+1) + 1)(2(n+1) + 1)}{6} $$

(*): Since $2n^2 + 7n + 1 = (n+2)(2n+3)$. The problem is solved by math induction.